# LTR to RTL in iOS Application [without closing Application]

Tags: right-to-left, arabic-support

When changing language within the application I need to change the application layout as per selected language.

For example, the base language is English; when the user changes it to Arabic I need to change UI as per RTL.

Is there any specific setting in storyboard or in ViewController for achieving LTR and RTL?

Answer (score 2):

To Manage RTL and LTR without closing application Swift 3.0.

**//RTL**

UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

**//applicationNavigationController is Application Default Navigation Controller**
            if let applicationNavigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "root") {
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = applicationNavigationController

**LTR//**

UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
           if let applicationNavigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "root") {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = applicationNavigationController

// Additional Tips while a deal with MMDrawer.

**AppDelegate**

var centerContainer:MMDrawerController?

**Implement MMDrawer Code inside one ViewController.**

let appdelegate=UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

```
    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSideMenuViewController") as! LeftSideMenuViewController



    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)


    appdelegate.centerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)

    appdelegate.centerContainer?.maximumLeftDrawerWidth = 250.0


    appdelegate.centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
    appdelegate.centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.all

    //////////
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(appdelegate.centerContainer!, animated: false)
```